# Server bandwidth required for Podcasts and live radio

Tags: bandwidth, requirements, internet-radio, podcast, dedicated-server

i need to set up a server that can host a podcast.
Actually there are 30 listeners during a live radio, but they can grow up.

What kind of server requirements do I need?

I usually buy dedicated server from Hetzner.

Comment: The description is really vague. Which codec? How much growth anticipated in what timespan? What did you figure out so far? etc.

Comment: I do not know what is the codec.
I think 100 listeners in 1 year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One dedicated server should be able to serve 100 listeners if you serve them an output of a reasonable bandwidth. You should check that with whoever did set it up for you and simply perform a performance test on the real system.

First of all, if I were you, I'd probably consult the Hetzner support staff if you're already a customer.

If you are unsure about the capacities of your server, then consider a hosting that offers dynamic expansion of the server capacity. Or [maybe cloud hosting is an option for you](http://aws.amazon.com/); it definitively gives you maximum flexibility. Of course, if you move your podcast to the cloud, hosting cost might rise if you suddenly experience a huge and unexpected rise in the number of your listeners, so you want to have a business model that creates some return on investment, or else put a limit to your booked capacity.